# C# Cannot return an instance of a class that implements an abstract class

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes sharing the same properties, and I made up an abstract class to regroup them and add only specific properties to each class implementing the abstract one.

However, in my method, C# does not seem to accept that I return an object of type T that implements my abstract class.

The abstract class and the implementation :

```
  public abstract class RapprochementResponse
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int IdPersonne { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateIdentification { get; set; }

}
```

The implementation :

```
 public class RapprochementGDAMoralResponse : RapprochementResponse
{
    #region GDA Moral

    public string? RaisonSociale { get; set; }

    public int SIREN { get; set; }

    public int DUNS { get; set; }
}
```

And the method :

```
public async Task<PagedList<T>> GetRapprochements<T>(RapprochementRequest request) where T : RapprochementResponse
    {
        var response = await _rapprochementRepository.GetRapprochementsByFiliale(request.Application, request.TypeDePersonne, request.CodeSAGE);
        var queryableResult = response
            .Select(x => _mapper.Map<RapprochementPPEResponse>(x))
            .AsQueryable();

        return PagedList<RapprochementPPEResponse>.ToPagedList(queryableResult,
            request.PageNumber,
            request.PageSize);
    }
```

The error is on the return line:

> unable to cast type `PagedList<RapprochementPPEResponse>` to `PagedList<T>`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't include the `PagedList` in your code. But the problem is probably that you're trying to cast a `PagedList<T>` to a `PagedList` (if you have both). That's not normally possible.

Comment: This is a "variance" question; a `Something<Foo>` doesn't inherit from `Something<Bar>`  (nor is it directly castable) just because `Foo : Bar` - unless you have defined `Something<T>` as `Something<out T>`

Comment: Why is T here at all, when the rest of the code deals with one specific type?